# Удаление скрытых файлов и файлов только для чтения

Tags: c#, файлы

Нашел интересную и нужную для меня тему на одном из форумов "Раньше удалял все файлы (в том числе скрытые и для чтения) в директории с помощью команды del /F /Q *.*. Решил попробовать сделать аналогичное на C#. В программе использую File.Delete(польный путь файла) для удаления файлов в директории. Получаю ошибку "Отказано в доступе для скрытых файлов и файлов только для чтения". Подскажите, пожалуйста, как удалять такие файлы в C#". Хотелось бы узнать, как эту проблему можно решить средствами C#, а не Win32 (чтобы можно было использовать в Linux с помощью Monodevelop)

Comment: Свойство FileInfo.Attributes попробуйте. [Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8#properties)

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось!